# Reading a line using scanf() not good?

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",line);
```

A friend of mine suggested that using `fgets()` to read a line as input would be a much better idea than using `scanf()` as in the statement above. Is he justified?

Comment: it should be scanf(" %[^\n]",line); close the brace in the argument..

Comment: He absolutely is. I always suggest using `fgets()` and avoiding `scanf()` completely.

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy Perfect example of why `scanf()` is not to be used.

Comment: `fgets()` is better.  But it is more like `scanf("%[^\n]",line);` (no space in the format).  The OP's `" %[^\n]"` will consume leading whitespace without storing in `line`.  `fgets()` with store the leading whitespace (that is not a `\n`).

Comment: Any `scanf` with `%s` or `%[` without a length specifier should be considered a bug. Now if you specified the length, it would have been an interesting question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) is safe to use because it avoid [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) problem, it scans only `num-1` number of char.

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

here second argument `num` is Maximum number of characters to be copied into str (including the terminating null-character).

For example suppose in your code a string array capacity is just `5` chars long as below.

```
 char str[5];
 fgets (str, 5, fp);  //5 =you have provision to avoid buffer overrun
```

Using above code, if input from `fp` is longer then `4` chars, `fgets()` will read just first `4` chars then appends `\0` (*, and discard other extra input chars, just stores five char in `str[]`*).

Whereas `scanf(" %[^\n]",str);` will read until `\n` not found and if input string is longer then `4` chars `scanf()` will cause of [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (as `scanf` will try to access memory beyond max index `4` in `str[]`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Will scanf() be a better choice, if I don't know how long my input string will be?

Comment: @amulous : Mr. YuHao given a very good link. read there, `scanf()`, `printf()` series of functions are good for formatted input/output

Answer (score 9):

**C FAQ** has some detailed explanation about `scanf`'s problem:

> More generally, `scanf` is designed for relatively structured, formatted input (its name is in fact derived from "scan formatted"). If you pay attention, it will tell you whether it succeeded or failed, but it can tell you only approximately where it failed, and not at all how or why. You have very little opportunity to do any error recovery.

see [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) for detail.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put: yes, `fgets` is a better choice.

I looked at your `scanf` format specifier and I was mystified. Understanding exactly what it does requires some time reading through the `man` pages.

Also, your `scanf` code is susceptible to buffer overruns.

Keep it simple and you will reduce the maintenance costs and avoid hard to find bugs!

Answer (score 3):

`fgets` will be better than this `scanf`.
There may be following issues with `scanf` as given in OP

1)buffer overflow as suggested by @Grijesh

2)possibly next `scanf` after this won't work because the newline is left in the input stream.(if you miss a blank space)

Answer (score 3):

Yes fgets is the better and safe way to read a line from the standard input.

Moreover there will more readability in the code. Look at the scanf statement given by you.

Any second person who sees it will be thoroughly confused. But whereas there will be more readeablity for fgets and it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Well, IMHO this is due to the fact that `scanf` doesn't force you to limit the input size, but `fgets` does.

If you read the documentation and use `scanf` properly, there really isn't much difference here:

```c
char line[256];

scanf("%255[^\n]%*c",line); // %*c to remove trailing \n
fgets(line, 256, stdin)
```

*Notice that I removed the leading space from the `scanf` format string.*
*I'll go back to this later.*

Both cases ensure we don't read more than we can.

But, from a safety perspective, we need to think:

- `fgets` force you to specify the size
- On `scanf` you need to remember to set array_capacity - 1

  - *`fgets` does this for you, so you actually pass in the capacity (or less)*
- "Man what does this format even mean??"

It's easy to forget scanf details, and when you deal with a vast team with different backgrounds in programming, some people might have more trouble to write code with such details and might not even understand the format string.
So in general using `fgets` is safer.

---

Now, regarding the leading space I removed.

When you use `fgets`, you lose the ability to ignore `whitespace` characters before input, so I had to remove that space to make both calls have almost the same result.

I guess we can't really say one way is "better" than the other, only that `fgets` is more readable and will ensure that you remember to pass the size. Which is something you could also achieve by encapsulating the `scanf` call into an input reading function that builds a format string correctly. Which would also enable you to skip leading `whitespace` characters before reading.

---

EDIT
Just so it's clear, my point here is that from a safety perspective (as in "not writing outside the character array"), both solutions are valid since you can limit the number of characters read on both of them.

The code I displayed is purely to show that you can have it limited to a certain size, not that they have exactly the same effect.
As *Andrew Henle* said, the `%*c` will indeed throw away one input character if the user provides more characters than the length we said to read.
But then again, that wasn't my point here and neither the question, IMHO.
I just put it there to be a bit closer to what `fgets` does since `fgets` removes the `\n` from the buffer if the input isn't bigger than the amount you are trying to read.

The question asks about `scanf` vs `fgets` with no particular intent in mind, as far as I understood.
At least one wasn't described on the question.

There are a bunch of extra things you need to consider, depending on what the application need to do, of course.

Some considerations for `fgets`:

- If your input has length `size - 1`, `\n` will be left in the buffer
  (which will mess up next character inputs...)
- If your input has length `< size`, `\n` will be inserted on the string
  (which you will need to remove, since you probably won't need it)
- If your input has length `> size`, remaining characters will be left on the buffer
  (which you will need to treat that somehow too)
- If you change the array length, you need to update the size on the call
- Can't ignore whitespace before extracting data

Some considerations for `scanf`:

- You need to decide if you can do the `%*c` safely or not
  (Honestly, it's better to not use `%*c`, but just have a leading space on the format string when reading characters, as you already are using on the code on your question)
- You need to remember to set `capacity - 1` on the width specifier
- If you change the array length, you need to update the `width` specifier
- Can ignore whitespace before extracting data
- Most people don't know format specifiers more complex than `%s`, `%d` and such, so it might be hard for other people on the team to understand the code
- If the input length matches the `width` you specified, `\n` will be left on the buffer
- If the input length is greater than `width`, remaining characters will be left on the input buffer too

Anyway, there's probably many more scenarios to consider, and many of them depend on the exact situation you need to deal with.

Both functions have their pros and cons.
I don't think either of them is inherently "bad", both of them require the user to use them correctly and treat some errors themselves, but, `fgets` certainly has the advantage of forcing you to provide a length and being more readable.

I hope my point is clearer now.

Comment: What happens if you feed your `scanf()` a line longer than the buffer?  That would discard a character that couldn't be recovered, wouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed. That's why I used "isn't much difference" (which means there is a bit of a difference) and "almost the same result". I'll add this information to my comment later so it's more explicit. But I throw back another question for you: what happens if you feed `fgets` with less characters than specified? It will insert the `\n` in the string. So both solutions have their pros and cons. But don't get me wrong, I'm also more favorable to using `fgets` I just feel that some people really don't know all the features scanf has. Some don't even know you can set a length limit, for example.

Comment: With `scanf("%255[^\n]%*c",line);` and the _first_ character read is `'\n'`, nothing is read into `line`.  `line` remains as is, possible lacking a null character.  `'\n'` remains in `stdin`, possibly setting up and endless loop if this function called again.

Answer (score 1):

> Reading a line using scanf() not good?

The primary objection to `scanf(some_format, buffer)` is a lack buffer overflow protection as with

```
scanf(" %[^\n]",line);  // Bad - no buffer overflow protection.
```

---

An alternative could use

```
char buffer[100];
scanf(" %99[^\n]",line);  // a little better
```

Yet that can read multiple leading lines (if only made of white-space), drops leading white-space, lacks an easy way to handle non-constant buffer widths, and it leaves the rest of the line (maybe only `'\n'`)  in `stdin`.  Does not return promptly if the first character was `'\n'`.

---

`fgets()` is better.

It still remains with problems though: lines longer than (example) 99 remain in `stdin` and reading embedded *null chracters* are hard to detect.

```
char buffer[100];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';  // Lop off potential tailing \n
```

---

Code could use `fgetc()` and crafted code to handle all cases as desired.  Yet reading 1 character at a time incurs significant performance overhead.

---

Non standard C library [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)  is fairly popular.

One downside: It does allow the user to cause code to consume excessive resources: An overlong line can allocate huge amounts of memory.

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t nread;

while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
```

---

The C standard library lacks a robust *get-line* function.  The closest is `fgets()`.

IMO, do not use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

Answer (score -1):

don't use fgets(...) instead use the following snippet:

```
char _x[7000];
    char* y;
while ( ! feof (_f) )
{
    fscanf(_f,"%[^\n]\n",_x);
            y=x;
}
```