# Pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am new to pointers and trying to use a pointer to the structure. But after the first entry, my program crashes. Kindly assist me.

Here's the structure definition:

```
struct students{//structure students definition
   char name[20];
   char RegNo[15];
   char CourseUnit[10];
   int score;
   char grade;
};
```

The grade should not be entered by the user but instead computed by the program.

Here's my code so far I have written:

```
int main()//start of main
{
    struct students *myStudPtr,myStud[SIZE];

    myStudPtr=&myStud[SIZE];

    int i;//declare variables
    int count;

    printf("How many students do you want to deal with?\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);//number of entries

    for(count=1;count<=i;count++) {
        printf("Enter student's name\n");
        scanf("%s",&(*myStudPtr).name);

        printf("Enter the student's registration number\n");
        scanf("%s",&(*myStudPtr).RegNo);

        printf("Enter the course unit\n");
        scanf("%s",&(*myStudPtr).CourseUnit);

        printf("Enter the marks scored\n");
        scanf("%d",&(*myStudPtr).score);
    }

    printf("NAME\tREGISTRATION\t\tCOURSE UNIT\tSCORE\t\tGRADE\n");//tabulates the output
    printf("%s\t", myStudPtr->name);
    printf("%s\t\t", myStudPtr->RegNo);
    printf("%s\t", myStudPtr->CourseUnit);
    printf("%d\t\t", myStudPtr->score);

    if(myStudPtr->score>100) {
        printf("Invalid\n");
    } else if(myStudPtr->score<40) {
        printf("FAIL\n");
    } else if(myStudPtr->score<50) {
        printf("D\n");
    } else if(myStudPtr->score<60) {
        printf("C\n");
    } else if(myStudPtr->score<70) {
        printf("B\n");
    } else if(myStudPtr->score>70) {
        printf("A\n");
    } else {
        printf("Invalid");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Kindly assist.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Going out of bounds on an array is undefined behaviour. That's not nearly the only problem, though.

Answer (score 9):

You have an [index-out-of bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-cs/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c) mistake that causes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) at runtime:

```
myStudPtr = &myStud[SIZE];
//                  ^^^^^ 
//                  wrong
```

According to declaration `struct students  myStud[SIZE];`, Maximum index value can be `SIZE - 1`. Remember array index starts with `0`.

**Edit**

As I can understand, you  have declared an array of struct, and wants to read `i` number of student's information from user using pointer to struct. But there are some more problems in your code e.g.  in for loop you always access *same* struct element:

```
for(count = 1; count <= i; count++)
    scanf("%s", &(*myStudPtr).name);
//                  ^   
//                  points to same struct element in array
```

This mistake is present in every `scanf()` and `printf()` statements.

Correct will be as follows:

1. Initialize pointer to the address of first element in array:

   ```
    myStudPtr = &myStud[0];
    //                  ^ first element at 0th index
   ```
2. Via pointer you can simply access struct's elements in any one of following two ways:

   **First**: for example to scan `score` value of a student:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &myStudPtr[count].score);
   ```

   **Note:** [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of `[]` 'array subscript operator' is higher then `.` 'member selection via object name operator' so you do not need `()` parenthesis. Also  precedence of `.` operator is higher then `&` ampersand operator so even you do not need any parenthesis to get address(for example `&(myStudPtr[count].score)` not needed).

   **Second**:  to scan `score` value of a student using pointer and `->` operator:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &(myStudPtr + count)->score);
   ```

   **Note**: `+` plus operator has lower precedence so we need parenthesis to overwrite precedence. 
   And precedence of `->` member selection via pointer operator higher then `&` ampersand operator so here also you do not need any parenthesis like `&((myStudPtr + count)->score)`.

Important to notes:

1. You should check entered value of `i` by user that must be less to `SIZE` (the size of strcut array) otherwise you may have undefined behavior in your code.
2. To read string use safe `fgets()` function instead of scanf to avoid buffer overflow. Read: ["Reading a line using `scanf()` not good?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good/17294869#17294869)

**One more side note:**

1. As you are new C programmer(I feel) you should read: [Indenting C Programs](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/indent_c.html) its a quick tutorial to learn indentation practice.
2. You should always keep space after `,` and `;` to make your code readable, and for the same reason an expression like `count<=i`  should be written as `count <= i`. Compare your for loop:

   ```
    for(count=1;count<=i;count++)
   ```

   And following that I would like to suggest you:

   ```
    for(count = 1; count <= i; count++){
        // code after one tab
    }
   ```

**Improve code:**

I would also like to suggest you to improve if-else coding style, your if-else part of code can be written as follows:

```
score = myStudPtr->score;
if(0 <= score && score <= 100){
  if(score > 70)
    printf("A");
  if(60 <= score && score < 69)
    printf("B");    
  if(50 <= score && score < 59)
    printf("C");    
  if(40 <= score && score < 49)
    printf("D");    
  if(score < 40)
    printf("FAIL");
}
else
 printf("Error: Invalid Entry!");
printf("\n");
```

- I removed many `else` statement, instead used &&.
- Removed redundant `{..}` braces pairs.
- Used local `score` variable instead `myStudPtr->score` to keep code look simple.
- Remove `\n` from each `pritf` statement instead add a new `printf` at the end (not very important).

**Last mistake:**

To print each students record you need a new loop within that you call `printf()` function and includes if-else logic to evaluate student grades.