# "Request for member in something not a structure or union"again

Tags: c

sorry if I ask a question that has been done many times before, but i have found no solution.

I have this typedef struct

```
typedef struct                          
    {
    int matrix[row][col];
    }Position;
```

And i create a variable

```
Position park[weeks];
```

then i call it in a subroutine

```
void foo(struct Position *park[weeks]...)
```

and then

```
park[s].matrix[i][j]=car[k].id;
```

and i have the "request for etc etc" error, in this line above. What am I doing wrong?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Does it give any error? why you don't try? What is `car[k].id`

Comment: Yes, give the error in the title! car[k].id is a variable, the problem is not there

Comment: read this answer: [Pointer to structure array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254623/pointer-to-structure/18254652#18254652)

Comment: Note: `void foo(struct Position *park[weeks])`  should be just `void foo( Position *park[weeks])` not need to use `struct`

Comment: is car an array of structs too with member named id.

Comment: Yes,car is an array of structs. But i think doesn't matter, if i remove car[k].id; and write park[s].matrix[i][j]=5; instead, gave me the same error

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i don't get it. All the variables start on 0.

Comment: Does `foo` know about `Position`. Is the decalration for `Position` visible to `foo`? This typically is done by having the declaration of `Position` given before `foo` coded or `#includ`ed in the same file as `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
park[s].matrix[i][j]=car[k].id;
```

to

```
park[s]->matrix[i][j]=car[k].id;
```

You've declared `parks` as an array of *pointers* to `Position`, so you have to use the operator `->` to access the `matrix` member.

Alternately, you could write

```
(*park[s]).matrix[i][j]=car[k].id;
```

but the `->` operator is a little cleaner.

Comment: also remove 'struct' in the foo() definition

Answer (score 1):

just delete the * in you foo. Then everything will be ok

```
void foo( Position *park[weeks]...)

==>

void foo(Position park[weeks]...)
```

Or

```
void foo(Position *park,...)
```

Like this:

```
typedef struct                          
{
    int matrix[2][2];
}Position;


void foo(Position *park)
{
    park[1].matrix[1][1]=5;
}

int main()
{
    Position park[2];
    foo (park);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why typedef struct should put in main, however , if you have to , maybe you can put the function in the main too :

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct                          
    {
    int matrix[2][2];
    }Position;

    void foo(Position *park)
    {
    Position *park1 = (Position *)park;
    park1[1].matrix[1][1]=5;
    };
    Position park[2];
    foo (park);
    printf("%d\n",park[1].matrix[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Already try this, gave me the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Comment: @user2699575 I think you need delete the `*` in you `foo` , If you want use variable `park`

Comment: @user2699575: `struct Position` and `Position` are two different types in C, the former of which doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: Hi @LidongGuo. If i remove struct i get the error "unknown type name", i think because the declaration of the type is in the main and is not globally visible. The problem is that in the declaration of the type i have to put a couple variables that are calcolated on run time, and for this i can't declare the new type struct out of the main.

Comment: @FabriNeral you can try put the foo in the main too.