# Segmentation fault after main returns (pointer to struct array)

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define VEL 2
typedef struct
{
    char ime[15];
    char prezime[15];
    int dob;
    int staz;
} employee;
void upis(employee *);
void ispis(employee *);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    employee radnik[VEL];

    upis(&radnik[VEL]);
    ispis(&radnik[VEL]);
    return 0;
}

void upis(employee * r)
{
    int i;

    printf("Upis podataka:\n==============\n");
    for (i = 0; i < VEL; i++)
    {
        printf("Upisite ime i prezime %d. radnika:\n", i + 1);
        scanf(" %15[^\n]", (r + i * sizeof(employee))->ime);
        scanf(" %15[^\n]", (r + i * sizeof(employee))->prezime);
        printf("Upisite dob i staz %d. radnika:\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &(r + i * sizeof(employee))->dob);
        scanf("%d", &(r + i * sizeof(employee))->staz);
    }
}

void ispis(employee * r)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < VEL; i++)
    {
        printf("Ime:%s\nPrezime:%s\n", (r + i * sizeof(employee))->ime,
               (r + i * sizeof(employee))->prezime);
        printf("Dob:%d\nStaz:%d\n\n", (r + i * sizeof(employee))->dob,
               (r + i * sizeof(employee))->staz);
    }
}
```

The code actually works but in the end always returns segmentation fault. I'm guessing I did something wrong with pointers and addressing struct elements. Please help and thanks in advance!!

EDIT: Thanks everyone each answer was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Error is expressions like:

```
(r + i*sizeof(employee))->ime;
```

Correct it as:

```
(r + i)->ime;
```

Read  [Pointer to structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254623/pointer-to-structure/18254652#18254652) To learn how to use pointer to struct.

Note  pointer arithmetic is different then integer arithmetic. When you add 1 to a pointer resulting address point to next location (you do not need to bother to calculate value). Accordingly in your code  if `r` point to n<sup>th</sup> employee in an array of employee then `r + 1` points to (n + 1)<sup>th</sup> employee.
To understand read [10.2 Pointers and Arrays; Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) and [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html).

**Edit:**

As @Jens Gustedt Notice correct your main code also as follows:

```
upis(radnik);
ispis(radnik);
```

If you wants to pass array to function (or first element's address).

Additionally avoid scanf to read line instead use fgets() read [Reading a line using `scanf()` not good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good/17294869#17294869).

Comment: Along with this, it would be good to explain for the OP that, in C, when you add an integer to a pointer, the pointer is incremented by an amount equal to that integer times size of the type pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

This code is fundamentally flawed:

```
employee radnik[VEL];

upis(&radnik[VEL]);
ispis(&radnik[VEL]);
```

Arrays in C are indexed from `0` on to `VEL-1` in your case. You are taking the address of of an element beyond the array and use it afterwards. This has no defined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: Actually this is first bug..I couldn't notice.