# How to access an array within a struct using a pointer

Tags: c

I want to access and element of an array that is within a struct using a pointer how do I do it ?

```
int int_set_lookup(struct int_set * this, int item){
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? It may be as simple as `this->arrayName[item]`, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Read [Pointer to structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254623/pointer-to-structure/18254652#18254652)

Comment: I'm warning you: giving a name `this` to one of your structs is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the call is setup and called like this:

```
struct int_set this[10];
int_set_lookup(this, 5);
```

the function `int_set_lookup()` can directly lookup the item:

```
int int_set_lookup(struct int_set* this, int item)
{
    /* where x is the item in the struct you want to lookup */
   return this[item].x;

    /* or, if int_set has an array member y, this accesses
       the 0th element of y in the item'th element of this */
    return this[item].y[0];
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to access `array within struct`, you are answering `array of struct`.

Comment: Oh you are suggesting both, but two return statements are confusing in answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume the array contained within the struct is "a" and p is the pointer to the struct:

```
p->a[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use arrow operator `->`

For example , `p` is a pointer to a struct `s1` , then

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {        
   struct s{
    int a[10]; // array within struct 
   };    
  struct s s1 ;
  s1.a[0] = 1 ; // access array within struct using strct variable 
  struct s *p = &s1 ;  // pointer to struct
  printf("%d", p->a[0]);//via pointer to struct, access 0th array element of array member

  return 0;
}
```

`a[0]` is accessed by `p->a[0]` ;