# Understanding operator precedence from the table

Tags: c++

I was going over the following [link](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_operators.html) and it states

> Operators between dashed lines have the same "precedence level", of
>   which you will note that there are 18

Now my question is what does the above statement mean. For instance if two operators are between the dashed lines like `->` comes before `[]` does this mean `->` has higher precedence than `[]` ?

Comment: No, you quoted it yourself. They have the same precedence since they're both between the same dotted lines.

Comment: Its in the page. I did not quote it myself

Comment: You certainly did quote it yourself: 'Operators between ... are 18'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes .. you are right..  also note that in case like when `*` and `/` comes in an expression,that's where associativity is considered... in such a case you have to evaluate from left to right...

In `a * b / c`, the operation    `a * b` is evaluated first and then `/` is evaluated.

In `a / b * c`, the operation   `a / b` is evaluated first and then `*` is evaluated.

Comment: Don't use sms words in answer like u r and use markdown

Answer (score 2):

> For instance if two operators are between the dashed lines like `->` comes before `[]` does this mean `->` has higher precedence than `[]` ?

Yes, both are at same precedence level but because of Left to right associativite for example:

```
a->b[i];
```

is parsed or equivalent as `(a->b)[i];`. This is useful when `a` is a pointer to structure and `b` is a array member of struct.

And an expression like:

```
a[i]->b;
```

same as `(a[i])->b;`. This is useful when `a` is an array of structure's pointers.

You don't need parenthesis.

For `*`, `.`, `->`, and `[]` operators you can read this answer ["Pointer to structure"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18254652/1673391).