# Implementing strcat using pointers

Tags: c

While doing some programs on strings, I have come across this little problem.
The question which was asked to me was this -
Write a pointer version of the function strcat(s,t) which copies the string t to the end of s.
I wrote the program as this -

```
#include<stdio.h>
void strcat(char *s, char *t);
int main()
{
    char *s1, *s2;
    printf("enter the first string\n");
    scanf("%s",s1);
    printf("Enter the second string\n");
    scanf("%s",s2);
    strcat(s1,s2);
    printf("Strings concatenated\n");
    printf("%s",s1);
    return 0;
}
void strcat(char *s, char *t)
{   
    while(*s++)
       ;
    while(*s++ = *t++)
               ;
}
```

I know i have done something(or many things) terribly wrong. Because whenever i try to run this code- it gives me segmentation fault. Like this-

> Enter the first string
>
> Hello
>
> Enter the second string
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It would be really helpful if someone points me out the flaw/flaws of my implementation. Thanks in advance.

Thank you very much guys, for such quick responses. But seems that wasn't the only problem. After writing the program like this-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void strcat(char *s, char *t);
int main()
{
    char s1[20], s2[20];
    printf("enter the first string\n");
    scanf("%s",s1);
    printf("Enter the second string\n");
    scanf("%s",s2);
    strcat(s1,s2);
    printf("Strings concatenated\n");
    printf("%s",s1);
    return 0;
}
void strcat(char *s, char *t)
{   
    while(*s++)
        ;
    while(*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}
```

It runs like this.

> Enter the first string
>
> Hello
>
> Enter the second string
>
> There
>
> Hello

It only prints the first string i have entered. Now i think i have made some mistake on that strcat function too.

Comment: You are not allocating memory to pointers.

Comment: Use some dynamic memory allocation when you do not have idea about length of strings.

Comment: It's a funny thing that your nickname is *allocated*.

Comment: @Michael exactly I was going to say the same thing :P Improvement in my above comment : *you are not allocating memory to be pointed at by pointers*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) In the `main()`, you have to allocate memory for both `s1` and `s2` pointers

```
char *s1=malloc(100*sizeof(char)), *s2=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
scanf("%99s",s1); //the "%99s" allow to avoid buffer overflow
```

And if you use gcc and your gcc>2.7 then you can use "%ms" in the `scanf()` in this way:

```
scanf("%ms",&s1);
```

with the `"%ms"`, the `scanf()` will allocate memory for `s1` pointer

2) and you have to add `s--` in

```
while(*s++)
    ;
s--; // add s-- here
while(*s++ = *t++)
    ;
```

because the s pointer is pointing in the next element of `'\0'` element. the s pointer should be pointed in the `'\0'` element before starting copy the second string

Comment: Using `sizeof (char)` (which is always 1 by definition) is kind of pointless and best avoided, in my opinion. It adds nothing but confusion.

Comment: @mohammed I am sorry, as a newbie in this forum it didn't occur to me that i can change accepted answers by clicking another answer. In this case i had clicked on the first answer before coming across your full answer. Fixed now. :)

Answer (score 7):

You don't allocate memory for `s1`, `s1` (or initialized with array), Value of both  `s1`, `s1` are garbage .

```
char *s1, *s2;
printf("enter the first string\n");
scanf("%s",s1);
```

This causes an undefined behavior.

Suggestion use either:

```
#define SIZE  1024
char s1[SIZE], s2[SIZE];
```

or dynamically allocate memory using calloc()/maloc() functions:

```
char *s1, *s2;
s1 = malloc(SIZE);
s2 = malloc(SIZE);
```

and lately free() memory explicitly when work done with `s1`, `s2`.

Additionally instead of unsafe `scanf()`  use `fgets()` function to avoid buffer overflow error. read [Reading a line using `scanf()` not good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good)