# Error while writing strcat() using pointers

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

I am trying to learn C with `The C programming Language by K&R`. I am trying to write a the `strcat()` program using pointers.

```
char *strcat (char *s, char *t){
    char *d;
    d = s;
    while(*s++);
    s--;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
    return d;
}

int main () {
    char *name1;
    char *name2;
    name1 = "stack" ;
    name2 = "overflow";
    printf("%s %s\n", name1, name2);
    printf("strcat out : %s", strcat(name1, name2));
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the ouput as

```
stack overflow
Segmentation fault
```

Why is it not working ? Can anybody clarify the mistake here..

Comment: Is this C, or C++? Why do you have both tags?

Comment: @Doorknob - the answer is the same for both languages.

Comment: You need to learn arrays and pointer, declare your `char name1[SIZE];` and `char name2[SIZE];` and replace assignment statements `name1 = "stack";` as `strcpy(name1, "stack");`,  `strcpy(name2, "overflow");`

Comment: Read: [Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing strcat using pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398180/implementing-strcat-using-pointers)

Comment: @PeteBecker: I think for C++ the answer would be "Use `std::string` instead of `char*`, for goodness sake!"

Comment: @FredLarson - the answer to "why does my code crash when I write to a literal string" is not "use `std::string`. That adds overhead without getting at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the pointers are pointers to literals, and not only are those *read only* the destination is not big enough to contain both the strings. For at least `string1` you would want to use an array of at least big enough size to contain both strings (including the terminator). Like:

```
char string1[128] = "Stack";
```

or

```
char string1[128];
strcpy(string1, "Stack");
```

Comment: so what modification should i make in this program ?

Comment: @noufal It's in my answer.

Comment: I found in the internet that we need to give declare like `char *name1 = malloc(100*sizeof(char));`. But this isn't working either ..

Comment: @noufal That's not correct either, since you later assign the pointer to point to the literal string, which makes you loose the original pointer returned by `malloc`. Instead you need top *copy* the literal string into the array. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
while(*s++ = *t++);
```

you dereference `s` which points to one-past-the-end of the char array `"stack"`. This causes `segmentation fault` error.

Comment: After `while(*s++);` is `s--;`.

Comment: It's okay to have a pointer to one-past-the-end of an array. As @johnchen902 says, the code decrements the pointer once it's found the end.

Comment: Thanx, I've improved my answer

Answer (score 0):

The program tries to append characters to the literal string `"stack"`. Don't do that; create an array of characters that's large enough to hold the result, copy the first string into the array, and then `strcat` the rest of the string.

Oh, and name your function something other than `strcat`. That name is already taken.

Answer (score 0):

```
 char *name1;
 char *name2;
 name1 = "stack" ;
 name2 = "overflow";
```

==>

```
 char name1[20];
 char name2[10];
 memcpy(name1,"stack") ;
 memcpy(name2,"overflow");
```