# Converting string of numbers from file into int array in C

Tags: c

I am having trouble converting a string of numbers from a file, say `1 2 55 -44 22` into an integer array.

My program so far works except for one bug, it interprets integers like `55` as `5` and `5`.

```
    int readNumbers(int array[], char* fname) {                                                                                                                                                                                               
 78     // TODO: will you read the comments above this function carefully???                                                                                                                                                                  
 79     // TODO: note those pre- and post-conditions!                                                                                                                                                                                         
 80     int numberRead = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 81     FILE* fp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 82     int ch;                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 83     int counter = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 84                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 85     // Use fopen to try to open the file for reading                                                                                                                                                                                      
 86     // TODO:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 87     fp = fopen(fname, "r");                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 88     // Test to see if the file was opened correctly                                                                                                                                                                                       
 89     // TODO:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 90     if (fp == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 91             printf("Error opening file\n");                                                                                                                                                                                               
 92             return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 93     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 94     // Now read until end of file                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 95     // TODO:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 96     while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 97             if (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n') {                                                                                                                                                                                                
 98                     array[counter] = ch - '0';                                                                                                                                                                                            
 99                     counter++;                                                                                                                                                                                                            
100                     numberRead++;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
101             }                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
102     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
103     if (ferror(fp)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
104             fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
105             return -1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
106     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
107     // Close the file pointer                                                                                                                                                                                                             
108     // TODO:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
109     fclose(fp);                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
110                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
111     // Return the number of items read                                                                                                                                                                                                    
112     return numberRead;  // can it be negative? if in doubt, read.                                                                                                                                                                         
113 }
```

I've looked elsewhere and many use fgets? I'm not sure if that would make a difference and want to hear opinions before making a change.

Comment: Please, try reading the file in `binary mode` and not `text mode` or use `fgets(...)`.

Comment: @nIcEcOw I see where you're coming from, but from an earlier question by Renren29 it appears that the numeric data is in plain ASCII in a text file.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Haha, I thought about that once, after writing my comment, as to what if - __"The file is a text file/Already written in text mode"__. That is why I kept it as comment. But Thank You, for bringing this to the front of my knowledge bank. Hopefully now I won't forget this, while giving some idea to someone :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how you can do it with `fgets`

```
char arr[PickYourSize];
char* ptr;
fgets(arr , sizeof arr , fp);
ptr = strtok(arr , " ");
while(ptr)
{
       array[counter++] = strtol(ptr , NULL , 10);
       ++numberRead;
       ptr = strtok(NULL , " ");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have one question. I've noticed that the size of arr leads to the number characters that are tokenized and accepted into the array. How do I make the size dependent on the number of characters in the file? For instance, if I put 20 as PickYourSize, then only part of the characters in the file are read.

Comment: well you can do a dynamic allocation , but before that you need to write a function to count the number of numbers in the file to allocate accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Your are using `fgetc`. It will do character reading. So you are facing cumbersome to meet your requirements. I request you to use `fscanf` and this is one of easy way too.

`fscanf` will return EOF if it fails before matching any of the arguments

Example code

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen ("/home/inputs.in", "r");
    int d=0;

    while ( EOF != fscanf ( fp, "%d ", &d ))
    {
            printf ("%d ", d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Due to the way they handle whitespace, including `'\n'`, `fscanf()` and `scanf()` are horrible, both for the programmer and the user. But once the data has been read (eg by using 'fgets()') `sscanf()` can be useful. See [Reading a line using scanf() not good?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good).