# task reminder program in c

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm writing a simple task reminder program in c which prints the given task after the certain amount of time. Here is a small portion of the code that I'm having problem with. Basically I'm having trouble with scanf() as the function is acting strangely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
   int hour,minute,curr_time,end_time;
   printf("input the hour and minute after which alarm will start in HH:MM : \n");
   scanf("%d:%d", &hour,&minute);
   char task[50];
   printf("Name of the task: \n");
   scanf("%s" , task);
   printf("your task is %s" , task);

return 0;
}
```

Now when I compile and run the program , the following occurs.

```
~$ ./a.out
input the hour and minute after which alarm will start in HH:MM : 
00.56
Name of the task: 
your task is .56
```

I cannot input the name of the task. As soon as I finish giving the hour and minute , the program ends without taking the task input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a line using scanf() not good?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good)

Comment: My compilation (MSVC) works perfectly well when I enter the time as prompted. The `%s` format spec ignores whitespace, so the `scanf` function is not satisfied as long as I keep tapping "Enter", I have to enter some text, which is truncacted at the first `space` character.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `:` as separator in `scanf` but while entering you're putting a decimal. Since `scanf` is expecting integers, it stops scanning at the first decimal point.

You can see the what the value of `hours` and `minutes` is by printing them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
   int hour,minute,curr_time,end_time;
   printf("input the hour and minute after which alarm will start in HH:MM : \n");
   scanf("%d:%d", &hour,&minute);
   char task[50];
   printf("Name of the task: \n");
   scanf("%s" , task);
   printf("your task is %s" , task);
   printf("hour is %d" , hour);
   printf("minute is %d" , minute);

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
input the hour and minute after which alarm will start in HH:MM : 
00.56
Name of the task: 
your task is .56
hour is 0
minute is 0
```

Either change the separator in `scanf` to a decimal or input your hours and minute as `00:56`

```
input the hour and minute after which alarm will start in HH:MM : 
00:56
Name of the task: 
test
your task is test
hour is 0
minute is 56
```

Comment: I have always been inputting hours and minutes as HH:MM , it seems that the program didn't respond for the first 15 minutes , now everything is working fine. Strange enough!

Comment: @JosephQuinsey Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into using FGETs instead of scanf. Right now after you are entering in the time, you are leaving a newline character in the buffer. When scanf goes to read in a string, it grabs the newline character. Making it seem as if it skipped your input.

Comment: The program works perfectly well when the time is entered in the correct format HH:MM. The `%s` format does not "grab the newline" in fact it refuses to accept a `newline`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have only the careless mistake.That is the **absence of & symbol in scanf**.

& have a special role in scanf. It represents the *address where the value need to be store.*

But,this **absence doesn't show any error**.

Due to this reason,you get an **output as your last entered value until reach new line character i.e. .56**

Be conscious,in some case it makes malfunctioning of entire program.