# Character replacement and substitution in C

Tags: c, string, replace, character

I'm trying to write a code which will replace character in the string user selects with character he/she does. Eg string `london` if user picks `o` and `a` then the output should be `landan`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

int function2(char str[], char drop, char sub) {
    int i = 0; int num = 0;
    while (str != NULL) {
        if (str[i] == drop) {
            str[i] = sub;
            num++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return num;
}

int main() {
    char d, s;
    char my_string[MAXLEN];

    printf("Input your string\n");
    scanf("%s", &my_string);
    printf("Input character you want to drop\n");
    scanf(" %c", &d);
    printf("Now character you want to substitute\n");
    scanf(" %c", &s);
    function2(my_string, d, s);
    printf("The string is %s\n", my_string);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It works up until the point where you actually print the altered string. All I get is `Segmentation fault (core dumped).` Note that code for function was not mine (I found it on some website, so owner of the original code for function2- Thank you in advance). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `while(str != NULL){` --> `while(str[i]){`. Also need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: why would `<stdlib.h>` be required? `<string.h>` is not even needed, `NULL` is defined in `<stdio.h>` among many standard headers.

Comment: @chqrlie for `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: good point. btw. returning `0` is defined to be semantically equivalent to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @chqrlie I know that.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Of course, the remark was intended for a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid using scanf. If you're interested for the reason and alternatives click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good).

But back to your problem

```
while(str != NULL)
```

is an infinite loop, because the pointer won't become `NULL`

```
while(str[i] != '\0')
```

should do the trick. It checks each time if you've already arrived at the end of the string.

Comment: Worked perfectly!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (str != null){
      while(str[i] != '\0'){
        if (str[i] == drop){
          str[i] = sub;
          num++;
        }
      i++;
      }
    }
```

str is a char array, with `str != NULL`, you check that the array point to a valid memory address.
With while loop and i++, you loop all characters in array, because the string ends with '\0', you need to stop the loop with `while(str[i] != '\0')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function runs an infinite loop because `str` never become `NULL`, but since `i` is incremented, `str[i]` will eventually access memory beyond the end of the string and at some point invalid memory causing a `Segmentation fault`.

Note also that it is not simple to tell `scanf()` the maximum number of characters to read into `my_string`.  Using `fgets()` is much safer and allows a whole phrase to be substituted.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

int function2(char str[], char drop, char sub) {
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == drop) {
            str[i] = sub;
            num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}

int main(void) {
    char d, s;
    char my_string[MAXLEN];

    printf("Input your string\n");
    if (!fgets(my_string, MAXLEN, stdin))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("Input character you want to drop\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &d) != 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("Now character you want to substitute\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &s) != 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    function2(my_string, d, s);
    printf("The modified string is %s", my_string);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```