# I want to have 100 structs in a loop or something like that

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char name[30];
    char address[30];
    int phoneNumber[30];
    char creditRating[30];
};

int main(){
    struct person p;
    printf("What is the person's name?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p.name);
    printf("What is the person's address?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p.address);
    printf("What is the person's phone number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &p.phoneNumber);
    printf("What is the person's credit rating?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p.creditRating);

    printf("The person's name is %s\n", p.name);
    printf("The person's address is %s\n", p.address);
    printf("The person's phone number is %d\n", p.phoneNumber);
    printf("The person's credit rating is %s\n", p.creditRating);
    return 0;
}
```

Can I have something like

```
For(i=0;i>=n;i++)
struct person [i];
printf("What is the person's name?\n");
scanf(" %s", [i].name);
printf("What is the person's address?\n");
scanf(" %s", [i].address);
printf("What is the person's phone number?\n");
scanf("%d", &[i].phoneNumber);
printf("What is the person's credit rating?\n");
scanf(" %s", [i].creditRating);
```

I want to have 100 structs with their inputs.  It's a bit hard to write them one by one like:

```
struct person p;
.....
struct person q;
.....

//and etc...
```

How can I avoid that?

Comment: `struct person p[100]; for(i=0;i<100;i++){...
scanf("%29s", p[i].name);...`

Comment: Be cautious.  Using `scanf("%s", …)` means the name and address fields cannot take any blanks.  You would probably do better with `fgets()` to read lines and `sscanf()` to analyse them when necessary.  Beware newline characters.  Also, you should check that the `scanf()` function calls succeed by testing the return value.  If it isn't 1, something went wrong.  Yes; you have to check every time.  Well done for not wanting to write the same code out 100 times.  That's important in programming.  Avoid repetition.

Comment: Is there a problem with the spacebar - as the code needs to be formatted to make it readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to have 100 structs with their inputs, but it is so hard to write them one by one...

**Just use an array of structures** of required size and loop over each element. Something like this:

```
struct person p[100]; //array of structures of required size

//loop over each array element
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("What is the person's name?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p[i].name);

    printf("What is the person's address?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p[i].address);

    printf("What is the person's phone number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &p[i].phoneNumber); 
    //NOTE: you are not scanning phone number correctly.
    //try using a loop or make it a string.

    printf("What is the person's credit rating?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p[i].creditRating);
}
```

Additionally, as others have suggested it's better to avoid using `scanf()`. Here's a link to [*why not use `scanf()`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17294869/5281962). But if you still want to use `scanf()`, it's good if you check for its return value. The return value of `scanf()` is number of items read, as you are reading a single string in every `scanf()`*(other than* `phoneNumber`*)* check if `scanf()` returns `1`

```
while(scanf(" %29s", string_name) != 1) {
    printf("wrong input");
}
```

Here, `%29s` is to avoid overwriting the space for *terminating null character* i.e, `'\0'` at the end of the string. The above `while` loop would not allow the program to proceed until a string is successfully scanned by `scanf()`.

And as [@IngoLeonhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2470782/ingo-leonhardt) has mentioned in comments, it'd be easier if you use string to take in the phone number instead of an integer array which requires a loop to place elements read in successive indices.