# Scanning multiple strings from the same line in a file (C)

Tags: c, struct, file-access

im trying to scan (perhaps using fgets) 6 different strings from the same line in a file that is accessed by the program. i used the following struct to hold the 6 different strings:

```
struct _entry {
    char subject[10];
    char prof_name[10];
    char prof_surname[10];
    int period;
    int credits;
    int pass_rate;
};
struct _entry entry[MAX_LINES];
```

if someone could help me on what i can do to scan 1 line from a file, and it will be 3 strings and 3 digits that i can assign to each of the struct values.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a line, the `sscanf()` or `strtok()` to parse it into separate fields.

Comment: You *have* used `scanf` before? Just use it to read all string and numbers with one format string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude **[Don't use `scanf`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good)**

Comment: `subject` may contain spaces?

Comment: @AryamanArora I'm not telling the OP to use `scanf` to read a line, but to actually scan and tokenize the different input parts needed using multiple format codes.

Comment: @AryamanArora Use the right tool for the job.  `scanf()` (with a width limit) is the best tool in a few situations,  `fgets()` is better in most, especially for those starting in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read file line by line using -

```
  fgets() or getline
```

> *( getline() is not portable. Its only for linux based application )*

Parse line using -

```
   strtok or strtok_r or sscanf
```

Convert parsed string into Integer using-

```
    atoi
```