# C - strcmp won't work with scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to use scanf() with strcmp. However, it doesn't work. I've included the right header files. I've tried out gets(). It works but I don't want to be vulnerable of a buffer overflow attack.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    char a[100] = "Hello World!";
    char b[100];

    scanf("%s", &b);

    if(strcmp(a, b) == 0) {
        printf("This should work!\n");
    }
}
```

I compile the program. Then, type Hello World! into the program. It won't show the message. Also, why does strcmp() show me all kinds of return values?

Please help.

Comment: `%s` of `scanf` does not include spaces.

Comment: Did you try to find out what the string that got read in was if it wasn't what you expected?  Shouldn't `strcmp` show different return values for different inputs, as its documentation says?

Comment: [notthecause] `scanf("%s", &b);` -->> `scanf("%s", b);`

Comment: Did you try to print b?

Comment: Yes, printing b was successful.

Comment: `fgets()` is probably best, but you could also use `scanf("%99[^\n]", b);`. This will leave the newline in the input stream.

Comment: Printing `b` could never have been successful unless you tested with a different text, and only one word. If you entered 'Hello world' and asked for `b`, you would have received 'Hello' in answer.

Comment: I don't belive you. If you add printf("%s", b) after the scanf and enter "Hello World" it will only print "Hello"

Comment: Wait. I just typed wow into it. Yes, it only says Hello.

Comment: @DavidBowling `scanf("%99[^\n]", b);` is also a problem when user enters only `"\n"`.

Comment: @chux-- a problem how? If the user enters only `"\n"`, then no characters are read into `b`, but `scanf()` will return. Of course, code needs to check the return value from `scanf()` before using `b`, e.g., in `strcmp()`. Is this what you meant? Note that my example did not have leading space, as the answer below did.

Comment: @DavidBowling The problem is that too often expectations are that `b[]` has updated data in it.  And with input like `'\n'`, that does not happen.  Yes, checking the return value of `scanf()` is good programming to detect that case.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the manual on scanf -- you will see that it stops scanning a %s at the first whitespace found

```
scanf("%s", b);
```

of 
    Hello World

will give you `Hello` but not `Wolrd`

Also note that scanf is equally vulnerable to buffer overflow, as you are still not limiting the size of the input in %s -- to limit the input you should probably try to do `%99s` making sure that you are not reading more than your 100 byte buffer still leavng space for your null termination.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17294869/668501) question you  need something like

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str)
```

to read everything up to the newline, and combining that with a length restrction, you would need something like

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",str)
```

Comment: OK. How do I fix it so it does both words?

Comment: You don't use `scanf`; you need something like `fgets`. And you need to trim the carriage return at the end.

Comment: You can still use scanf, but it does not make it easier

Comment: I've tried fgets(b, 100, stdin). That still doesn't do much. It prints both words but doesn't go onto the if statement.

Comment: @AshlandSimpson  -- did you try the code I suggested.?

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]",str)` does not read "everything up to the newline,". It first consumes leading whitespace including newlines - then reads everything up to the next newline.

Comment: @xing -- that is terrible advice as that can result in a different buffer overflow -- why don't you move this into a separate answer instead of adding comments here?

Comment: @xing -- I can construct input that is 100 bytes long without a newline and the strcspn will modify memory beyond the 100 buffer length.

Comment: @Soren: `strcspn()` stops at the first newline or null byte.  Since `fgets()` always includes a null byte, even when it does not reach a newline, the `strcspn()` idiom is safe.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%99[^\n]",str)` (with or without 99) will have trouble if line input is only `"\n"` --> `str` is not changed and `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.  `fgets()` is a better tool to real a _line_.