# How to read a line using scanf in c++?

Tags: c++, printf, scanf

I'm trying to use "scanf" to read a string line: "is it not working", but I don't know if it's even possible to implement it in this particular example.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <limits>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        string s = "Just an example of, why ";
        int number;
        double doub;
        string longText;
 
        scanf("%d %lf %s", &number, &doub, &longText); //Read a line ex ("is it not working")    
        printf("%d\n%lf\n%s", number+i, doub+d,s+longText); //Print all the values, but not printing s+longText

}
```

[Image showing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nexEV.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a line using scanf() not good?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294809/reading-a-line-using-scanf-not-good)

Comment: [Turn on your compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bbPqKE)

Comment: And ALWAYS check the return code to make sure you got all of the inputs you wanted. Users are vicious fiends. Those that aren't actively trying to break your program are going to break it by accident. Never trust them.

Comment: If your input is "is it not working", how do you think the program will extract numbers from it?

Comment: Read this carefully, and pay attention to the format specifiers: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf - not all of those that you use are correct as @chris points out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%s` in `printf`/`scanf` family stands for char array, not `std::string`. If you want to get line, use `std::getline`. If you want to use `std::string` buffer for stdio functions, use `std::string::data` function, but I wouldn't suggest that as buffer-overflow is likely, especially for something like get-line.